# Get a repetition count of an animation

Tags: android, animation

Is there another way than doing our own counter to know how many times an animation has been repeated? (to produce different effects depending on the times it has been repeated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having your Animation in `yourAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);` (RESTART-mode) then you can set a repeat counter to the animation or the animation set.

```
yourAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
yourView.startAnimation(yourAnim);
```

When you set your repeat count, you can control the number of times the animation will repeat.
Above we have set the repeat counter to indefinitely.

Comment: I don't want to set a number of repetition. Maybe I didn't explain correctly. I want to know, at a certain time, how many times an animation has been repeated.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Then you have to do your own counter and put it inside the an onCompletion-listener to keep track of how many times. 
You maybe have to do like this; but I can be wrong.